# Close dialog window on webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, dom, html

I need to trigger some actions inside someone else's webpage. I have this code so far:

```
IHTMLElementCollection DeleteCollection = 
    (IHTMLElementCollection)myDoc.getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach (HTMLAnchorElement buttonDelete in DeleteCollection){
    if (buttonDelete.title != null && buttonDelete.title.StartsWith("Delete")){
        buttonDelete.click();
            // problem goes here
        myDoc.activeElement.click(); 
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
}
```

This dialog pops up:

[image]

I tried `myDoc.activeElement.click();` and `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");` but the dialog seems to be out of the page, so I don't know how to trigger the `OK` button. How can I close the window?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot close a browser dialog programatically. What you can do is hijack browser popup behavior. This might work for you:

```
window.confirm=function(){ return true; };
window.alert=function(){ return true; };
window.prompt=function(){ return "textOfMyChoice"; };
```

Basically, insert this javascript before clicking your buttons. If you want to later restore the popup behavior store them in another global variable.

Comment: Nice one!! ... It worked with `ie.Navigate("javascript:(function(){window.confirm=function(){return true}})()")` and then `anchor.click();`

Comment: I figured it would work. Note that it is not the answer to the question how to "Close dialog window on webpage" but an answer to how to "Prevent popup dialon on webpage"

Comment: Really simple and impressive!! .. I had never noted `confirm` and those methods was on `window` object

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, any anchor tag in your example has a javascript native confirm dialog.
You don't close programmatically this dialog.

But you can change javascript for all anchor element and substitute confirm dialog with your custom jQuery dialog. this way allow you to have full control on this dialog: close, hide, set timeout etc etc.

Transform

```
<a href="..." onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')" ... >...</a>
```

to

```
<a href="..." onclick="return openMyjQueryDialog('are you sure?')" ... >...</a>
```

So, user can continue with normal behavior, your script can take full control on all dialog element.

Comment: How would he update content inside _someone else's webpage_? Also, he didn't mention jQuery